# Cross reference text from two separate cells and display match in adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using Excel v16.22 on a Mac.

Is this possible?

I have two columns that I need to cross reference. I need to check that text in column A appears in column B (as per the text highlighted in my example below) and have some feedback in column C to confirm whether or not the text appears in both. Whether that's a 'Yes' or 'No'. If the text doesn't match then I know I need to double check that information. I have 3,500 rows to check so that's why I wanted to automate the confirmation process.

Hope this makes sense.

[image]

For confirmation, I have researched this online and tried a couple of solutions. One of them I just couldn't get it to work, and another solution just didn't achieve the outcome I was after.

Appreciate any help.
Dave

Hi Mark, just adding this image in reply to you answer so I can show you the negative response.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a `Find` formula to search for the text in Column B in the text from Column A. Breaking down this formula I do two things.

First, I use the find function to see if a value is pulled, if any number appears you know the text is found, so if it's 0 or higher, than say "Yes".

Secondly, if the text *isn't* there it will instead give an error, so I put this within an `Iferror` formula where an error would mean no text match. The first instance of "No" functionally doesn't do anything and can be excluded, but I left it here so `If` fans could see the logic written out.

`=iferror(if(find(A2,B2)>=0,"Yes","No"),"No")`

Comment: Hi Mark, I really appreciate your help but unfortunately it keeps coming back with a negative value even though the text exists. The only way I could get it to work was making sure the only text in column B matched the text in column A, as opposed to column B simply including the same text.

Comment: Hi @Frasier013 I realize I read your question backwards. I'm going to adjust my answer and it should work. I read it as check A for text in B, not the other way around.

Comment: Hi @Mark S you're a star!!! Thank you so much, it's really appreciated.

Comment: @Frasier013 so I take it this answered your question then?

Comment: S Yes it did thank you.